# How to find the Index number of the array in C

Tags: c, arrays, indexing

I have this code sample. I need to get the `maxDay` from the array which has the highest value from the array elements. **(In this case it is 7.0)**. So I need to get the its index value **(that is 24)**. But I can't get the desired output.

This is the output **I'm getting**:

> Day of the Month with Maximum Usage: 12
>
> Maximum Usage in Units: 7.00
>
> Day of the Month with Minimum Usage: 4
>
> Minimum Usage in Units: 0.00
>
> Average Usage for the Month: 1.80
>
> Total Usage for the Month: 50.40

**But the CORRECT output should be:**

> Day of the Month with Maximum Usage: 24
>
> Maximum Usage in Units: 7.00
>
> Day of the Month with Minimum Usage: 28
>
> Minimum Usage in Units: 0.00
>
> Average Usage for the Month: 1.80
>
> Total Usage for the Month: 50.40

I tried this code, but it looks like not working. I can't find where I have gone wrong. Can you please help me???

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    float maxUsage=0,minUsage=1000,avgUsage,totUsage=0;
    int maxDayI=0,maxDayJ=0,minDayI=0,minDayJ=0,count=0,i,j;
    float usage[4][7]={{1.2, 2.1, 0.8, 0.0, 1.0, 1.3, 4.0}, 
                       {1.5, 3.2, 1.0, 1.3, 4.0, 1.5, 3.2}, 
                       {2.3, 0.4, 1.2, 2.1, 0.8, 0.0, 2.6}, 
                       {2.1, 1.7, 7.0, 1.2, 2.1, 0.8, 0.0} };
    for(i=0;i<4;i++){
        for(j=0;j<7;j++){
            totUsage=totUsage+usage[i][j];
            if(usage[i][j]>maxUsage){
                maxDayI=i;
                maxDayJ=j;
                maxUsage=usage[i][j];
            }else if(usage[i][j]<minUsage){
                minDayI=i;
                minDayJ=j;
                minUsage=usage[i][j];
            }               
        }
    }
    printf("Day of the Month with Maximun Usage: %d\n",(maxDayI+1)*(maxDayJ+1));
    printf("Maximum Usage in Units: %.2f\n",maxUsage);
    printf("Day of the Month with Minimum Usage: %d\n",(minDayI+1)*(minDayJ+1));
    printf("Minimum Usage in Units: %.2f\n",minUsage);
    printf("Average Usage for the Month: %.2f\n",totUsage/28);
    printf("Total Usage for the Month: %.2f\n",totUsage);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: a minimal example would make the error obvious....

Comment: You might want to go for learning how to use a debugger.

Comment: What do you mean @KarolyHorvath

Comment: This does not help me :(

Comment: Maybe this helps: 1) take the [tour] 2) read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 1):

The index calculation process seems to be wrong. What you may need is something like (explanation below)

```
 ((maxDayI)* ELEM ) + maxDayJ + 1;
    ^^        ^^        ^^     ^^
     |         |         |       |
saved value    |        offset    Handle 0-based indexing
 of i        No. of element
```

where `ELEM` is the element number per 1-D array, i.e, 7.

Same goes for the minimum element, too.

**Point to note:** In case you have multiple days with maximum / minimum values, only the first one appearing will; be considered. If you want a specific record among multiple values to be chose, you need to add the logic for that.

Comment: Won't produce the desired output either. For that I believe the `if`need to use ">=" and "<=".

Comment: Sorry Sir, I don't get this. Where Am I actually gone wrong?

Comment: @Yunnosch This should be working here, but in general you're right/

Comment: Compare your code to the proposed code. Also go through each element of your 2D array and calculate the index with the two methods. See which one is correct.

Comment: @user7941771 You are trying to 0-balance the index too early.... and the first index for `usage` does not need balancing, at all.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Sorry, I was more shooting at the logic in the question than at your decent code. However, if OP tries your answer and sees the difference to desired output, but does not see the logical error on their side, they will believe your anser is wrong. I see your edit, seems clear now.

Comment: Does anyone know how to solve this? I'm really exhausted checking this over thousands of times. Can you please stop giving hints and tell me **In which part of my question i have gone wrong**???

Comment: Why does it not need to be balance? @SouravGhosh

Comment: @Yunnosch: Which two methods are we talking about?

Comment: Yours ending in the undesired output and the one proposed by Sourav.

Answer (score 0):

This is the Answer:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    float maxUsage=0,minUsage=100,avgUsage,totUsage=0;
    int maxDayI=0,maxDayJ=0,minDayI=0,minDayJ=0,count=0,i,j;
    float usage[4][7]={{1.2, 2.1, 0.8, 0.0, 1.0, 1.3, 4.0}, 
                       {1.5, 3.2, 1.0, 1.3, 4.0, 1.5, 3.2}, 
                       {2.3, 0.4, 1.2, 2.1, 0.8, 0.0, 2.6}, 
                       {2.1, 1.7, 7.0, 1.2, 2.1, 0.8, 0.0} };
    for(i=0;i<4;i++){
        for(j=0;j<7;j++){
            totUsage=totUsage+usage[i][j];
            if(usage[i][j]>maxUsage){
                maxDayI=i;
                maxDayJ=j;
                maxUsage=usage[i][j];
            }else if(usage[i][j]<minUsage){
                minDayI=i;
                minDayJ=j;
                minUsage=usage[i][j];
            }

        }
    }
    printf("Day of the Month with Maximun Usage: %d\n",(maxDayI*7)+(maxDayJ+1));
    printf("Maximum Usage in Units: %.2f\n",maxUsage);
    printf("Day of the Month with Minimum Usage: %d\n",(minDayI*7)+(minDayJ+1));
    printf("Minimum Usage in Units: %.2f\n",minUsage);
    printf("Average Usage for the Month: %.2f\n",totUsage/28);
    printf("Total Usage for the Month: %.2f\n",totUsage);
return 0;
}
```